# Best Bluetooth GPS for marine applications

Tags: gps, android

What is the best GPS to get as an add on for an Android (ASUS tf300)? This is for a marine application I am writing.

1. I need sub 5 meter accuracy.
2. Would like decent accuracy at moderate speeds.
3. I don't want to spend more than 120 USD.
4. Must be Bluetooth since device doesn't have USB

Battery life is important since I'll be on a boat for 12+ hours at a time - the GPS will be in standby mode some of this time - battery should be able to run at least 6 hours in active mode without charging

I'm assuming that most of the devices on the market today are waas enabled (this is what I want right?). I've looked at some globalsat and dual models but not sure what is the best.

Please be gentle as I'm a noob when it comes to GPS technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cheap end ($100+tax)

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Dual-Electronics-XGPS150A-Universal-Bluetooth/dp/B006M49G80/ref=dp_ob_title_ce](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006M49G80)

or high end

http://www.trimble.com/construction/marine/SPS361_SPS461.aspx?dtID=overview

($3000+tax)
[image]

Comment: yes that is the dual model I was thinking of. There were some other globalsat models I was looking at as well - I think I just need to bite the bullet and pick something. Ill probably go with the model you listed above. The ones Im looking at look fairly similar in specs. Thanks for the feedback! As far as the trimble goes ... someday when my android app makes me a millionaire! Here is to dreaming =)

Comment: just put the order for the dual xgps150a - Ill put a short review here once I get it.